# Redis::CommandError: ERR Client sent AUTH, but no password is set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, redis

This has to be some wrong config

I installed redis on localhost.

When trying to connect to it through Rails console

```
Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)
```

I can't send commands and I get

```
Redis::CommandError: ERR Client sent AUTH, but no password is set
```

I don't recall setting a password, nor do I know where to see if a password has been set

if I use a different URL (like rediscloud or redistogo) I can send commands (setting the password accodingly)

From what I understand the error says that I am sending a password, but redis doesn't have a password. But, as you can see, I am not setting any password..

Is there a way to debug this?

Comment: Can you check if the REDIS_URL environment variable is set? If that's the case, the Redis client you are using may be picking the password from it.

Comment: thanks, that was exactly the case.. Eventhough I explicitly declare the host and password, it takes the password from the redis_url which I didn't use..

Comment: Same issue in python. I don't send any pass, but got this error.

Comment: Hello, Iam facing the same issue can you please help me where should i set it?

Comment: Check the redis url environment variable, it might point to a server that requires a password or not

Comment: Thanks @NickGinanto it worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can debug you client's communication from Redis' side by using the [MONITOR](http://redis.io/commands/monitor) command. MONITOR provides a stream of the commands that Redis processes, so if your Ruby client issues and uncalled-for AUTH you'll be able to catch it there.

Comment: thanks, I am noticing that I am sending a password, but I don't have this password set anywhere in the code.. :(. even using plain irb and trying to send command would send that password.. Is it possible that in the past I've set that password and it is stored somewhere?

Comment: You saved my day :) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, but happier that it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

I got same Issue and it was that am trying to connect while no password had been set on radis server and my code was sending the pass as null

edit redis.conf and setting a password fix it

```
requirepass pass_here
```

Answer (score 1):

follow the steps (redis.conf location can be diffrent):

```
vi /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
```

uncomment:

```
# requirepass foobar
```

stop and start redis:

```
brew services stop redis
brew services start redis
```

from redis-cli:

```
AUTH foobar 
CONFIG SET requirepass "foobar"
```

All done