# Cannot create redis cluster (Sorry, can't connect to node)

Tags: linux, redis, redis-cluster

I'm trying to follow the [redis cluster tutorial](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial) but whenever I try to run:

```
./redis-trib.rb create --replicas 1 127.0.0.1:7000 127.0.0.1:7001 \
  127.0.0.1:7002 127.0.0.1:7003 127.0.0.1:7004 127.0.0.1:7005`
```

I get the error:

> [ERR] Sorry, can't connect to node 127.0.0.1:7000

The server is running and I can connect to port `7000` using

```
redis-cli -p 7000
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had `REDIS_URL` set in `.bashrc` from a previous project.  Apparently the redis gem was setting the password from that url for ALL redis connections (even though I was not using the url for my cluster).

Thanks to [soveran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1644405/soveran) for pointing out this posibility in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356435/rediscommanderror-err-client-sent-auth-but-no-password-is-set)

Comment: What does `REDIS_URL` do?